# No puedo filtrar en POSTGRESQL una columna creada en el select

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo esta query:

```
SELECT l.*,ca.txt AS area_cuota,e.txt AS est,
                               (l.estado ='C' 
                               AND id_propuesta is null) AS puede_reabrir,
                               EXTRACT('year' FROM l.f_alta) AS ej                              
                        FROM cuota.lote l
                        LEFT JOIN cuota.estado_lote e USING(estado)
                        LEFT JOIN cuota.area_cuota ca ON ca.id_area_cuota = l.id_area_cuota 
                        WHERE ej = 2021
```

Pero el problema esta en que extraigo el año de la fecha de alta como se puede ver en la línea 4 y creo una columna ej de allí pero lo quiero filtrar en el WHERE y siempre me tira que la columna ej no existe. Probé también con l.ej y demáses.

Como podría aplicarle un filtro a esa columna?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los alias del `SELECT` no están soportados en PostgreSQL, hasta ahora,en el predicado. Puedes resolver tu problema colocando la expresión completa en el predicado(`WHERE`):

```sql
SELECT l.*,ca.txt AS area_cuota,e.txt AS est,
                               (l.estado ='C' 
                               AND id_propuesta is null) AS puede_reabrir,
                               EXTRACT('year' FROM l.f_alta) AS ej                              
                        FROM cuota.lote l
                        LEFT JOIN cuota.estado_lote e USING(estado)
                        LEFT JOIN cuota.area_cuota ca ON ca.id_area_cuota = l.id_area_cuota 
                        WHERE EXTRACT('year' FROM l.f_alta) = 2021
```

Comment: Genial! No sabia esa manera... Lo solucione de una manera rara, pero claramente la que me mostras es mucho mas óptima.